# как указать кодировку в Spring Data JPA?

Tags: кириллица, spring-data

данные выводятся в виде ??? вместо русских букв.
вот файл `application.propertie`s:

> spring.datasource.url:jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost:3050/D:/DB/mybase.gdb
>   spring.datasource.driverClassName:org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver
>   spring.datasource.username:SYSDBA spring.datasource.password:masterkey
>   spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto:update spring.jpa.show-sql:true
>   spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql:true
>   spring.datasource.connectionProperties:useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=UTF-8;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй так:

`spring.datasource.url = jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost:3050/D:/DB/mybase.gdb?encoding=UTF8`

Comment: спасибо, получилось!

Comment: @Света [тут](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/jaybird/wiki/Character-encodings) и [тут](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/jaybird/wiki/Connection-properties) еще инфы немного ))